# counting characters (again!)

Tags: c++

Suppose I would like to count characters in some `mFile` like this:

```
  while((c = getc(mFile)) != EOF){
    chars[c]++;
  }
```

If I try to show them:

```
  for(int f=0;f<256;f++) {
    if(isprint(f) && chars[f]>0) 
      cout << (char)f << " " << (int)chars[f] << endl;
  }
```

All characters print fine. But if I do

```
      cout << " " << (int)chars[32] << endl;
```

Then it doesn't print the number... just some large `int`, I guess, because it's negative. What am I doing wrong? Does `getc` break on, or not count spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Its obviously a simple program. Would it kill you to post a compilable version that shows the problem!

Comment: That's the trouble; char can store up to 127 (signed) or 255 (unsigned).  You want to keep the counts in (unsigned) integers of some sort.  If you think you'll be processing files bigger than a few GB, you need to worry about overflows of plain 'unsigned int'.  However, it is unlikely that you'll be doing that so 32-bit `unsigned int` will probably do.

Comment: Absolutely, Jonathan. I see it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, I'd say the problem is likely to be that `char` is signed on your platform, and you have more than 127 spaces in your input file, so `chars[32]` is wrapping and becoming negative.

Why not use a more appropriately-sized type for your counters?

Comment: Exactly. Just because the OP's counting chars, that's no reason to store said counts in char variables.